# Using awk how do i find numbers in a file between 200 and 400?

Tags: bash, file, awk, sum, range

I have a file that reads something like:

```
500 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 (200) 
200 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2
350 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3
400 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 (300)
```

```
if [ -f file.txt ]      
then
    echo "Input your number:"
    read number
    if [ $number -ge 200 ] && [ $number -le 400 ]
    then 
        echo "The number that matched the file are:"
        awk $1 >= 200 && $8 <= 400 {print} numbers.txt
    else 
        echo "Number must be between 200 and 400."
    fi
```

Trying to extract numbers between 200 and 400 and then print the whole line and I just keep getting the while file as output instead

Comment: `awk $1 ...` - that `$1` will be the first argument to the _bash_ function you are in and not the first column in `numbers.txt`.

Comment: By using awk $1 and $8 I thought it would pull out the 1st and 8th field in the file, but I just get the whole file as output

Comment: You need to prevent bash interpolation. Use single quotes: `awk '$1 >= 200 && $8 <= 400 {print}' numbers.txt`. For the file you've shown `$8 <= 400`  will be true on _all_ lines though

Comment: I put that line in and I'm still getting the whole file, even if the user input is say 250 its still showing the whole file, would there be an alternative way rather than using the $1 and $8 field?

Comment: As I said, `$8 <= 400` is true in all the lines you've shown. If there are only 7 columns, then `$8` will be zero, which is less than or equal to 400. `(200)` and `(300)` are not numbers so when doing a numerical comparison, they will be treated as zero. Again making the condition true.

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how i would change it altogether? i tried awk '$1 -ge 200 && $8 -le 400 && $8 != 0 {print}' numbers.txt and it didnt work
Im just starting at this so any suggestions would help my understanding of it

Comment: Well, you would need to extract the numeric part from `$8` since `$8 != 0` will be false in all your rows. Perhaps `awk '-F[ ()]+' '$1 >= 200 && $8 > 0 && $8 <= 400 {print}' numbers.txt` would be more successful. Here I made `(` and `)` into field separators too.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is `file.txt` supposed to be `number.txt`? How does the value of the shell variable `number` relate to your awk script comparing the 1st and 8th fields from `number.txt` to the hard-coded numbers `200` and `800`? What does `Trying to extract numbers between 200 and 400 and then print the whole line` actually mean? Once we know what it is you're really trying to do then we can best help you. And please don't just keep repeating `text` in your example - show some truly representative values.

Comment: I have a feeling you're planning to use awk to extract the lines that start and end with numbers between 200 and 400 and then use some other tool (shell? another call to awk? bc?) to compare that set of lines against the value of the `number` shell variable - definitely do not do that.

Comment: do both numbers (1st field, 8th field) have to be between 200 and 400?

Comment: yes file.txt is supposed to be numbers.txt

Comment: yes file.txt is supposed to be numbers.txt 
i want the to enter any number between 200 and 400. if i enter 200 I want the terminal to print out all lines where it says 200 or less, so
500 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 (200)
200 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2

if 400 is entered I understand that the whole file will print 


yes the numbers must be between 200 and 400 
@Ed Morton , why definitely do not do that?

Comment: @user88888888 because that's wasting code and resources. It's like cutting down all of the trees in a forest and then picking one to be your Christmas tree rather than picking the Christmas tree and then cutting down just that one. The right solution will call awk once to do all of the calculations and text manipulation.

Comment: @Ed Morton so would you know of the right solution will call awk once to do all of the calculations and text manipulation.
if it helps the file numbers could be anything I guess as long as the terminal sends back the full line(s) with the number that are less than or equal to user input between 200 and 400

Comment: I'm still trying to understand [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176347/using-awk-how-do-i-find-numbers-in-a-file-between-200-and-400?noredirect=1#comment137822467_78176347). It'd be much easier for us to help you if you'd [edit] your question to state your requirements and show sample input including some "number" a user might enter and the expected output given those "number"s.

Answer (score 0):

change the `awk` line to

```
awk '$1>=200 && (NF>7) && substr($8,2,length($8)-2)+0<=400' numbers.txt
```

use `substr` to extract the number from the paranthesized expression and the added number of fields check will avoid false matches when there is no 8th field.

Comment: That `substr()`s output will, by definition, be of type string so the comparison against `400` will be done alphabetically and so `300000` will be considered less than `400`. You could change `substr($8,2,length($8)-2)` to `substr($8,2)+0` to solve that and shorten the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This MAY be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file='numbers.txt'

if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
    IFS= read -r -p 'Input your number: ' tgt

    awk -v min=200 -v max=400 -v tgt="$tgt" '
        BEGIN {
            if ( (tgt < min) || (max < tgt) ) {
                printf "Number %d must be between %d and %d.\n", tgt, min, max |"cat>&2"
                exit 1
            }
        }
        {
            delete nums
            nums[$1]
            if ( NF == 8 ) {
                nums[substr($8,2)+0]
            }

            for ( num in nums ) {
                if ( num+0 <= tgt ) {
                    print
                    next
                }
            }
        }
    ' "$file"
fi
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Input your number: 100
Number 100 must be between 200 and 400.
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Input your number: 200
500 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 (200)
200 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Input your number: 300
500 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 (200)
200 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2
400 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 (300)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Input your number: 400
500 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 text1 (200)
200 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 text2
350 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3
400 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 text4 (300)
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Input your number: 500
Number 500 must be between 200 and 400.
```

Comment: I thought I was to avoid substr?

Comment: @user88888888 Is that because of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78176347/using-awk-how-do-i-find-numbers-in-a-file-between-200-and-400/78176886?noredirect=1#comment137822166_78176634)? That was about `substr()` outputting a string and then trying to use it in a numeric comparison. There's nothing wrong with using `substr()` but if you want to do a numeric comparison on it's output then you have to convert it's output to a number first, e.g. by adding `0`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Variable-Typing for types in awk.

Comment: I really appreciate your help in this, that link is very useful too thank you!